# Method for pulling entries that have a specific image linked?

Tags: assets

Let's say that I have an Assets field on a single page where someone can add a bunch of images to a "gallery" on that page. Is there a way to perform a query and return the entries from a channel where these images are used as well?

Ideally, I'm trying to get the URL's to all of the listing entries where any of these images are also used, but without the admin explicitly relating them to those entries on the single page. There's no explicit relationship between them, other than the same images were used on both the single and channel entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `relatedTo` for that:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection').relatedTo(myAsset) %}
```

Or

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({ section: 'mySection', relatedTo: myAsset }) %}
```

Check out [the documentation on relationships](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize that relatedTo would work without explicitly relating items.

Comment: relatedTo is one of those magic ingredients that makes Craft look like something out of Harry Potter. :)